# Smooth FPS change via FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 240FPS video from GoPro and I want to slow down it to 30FPS linearly. For this I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i raw.mp4 -filter_complex "[v:0]setpts='lerp(2,8,T/5)*PTS" -r 30 output.mp4
```

* 5 is video duration in seconds

The problem is that the resulting video stutters pretty heavily. But if I use a fixed `setpts`, like `setpts=8*PTS`, then everything is fine.

How to make smooth FPS transition via FFMPEG?

Answer (score 2):

For video,

```
ffmpeg -i raw.mp4 -filter:v "setpts='if(between(T,0,1),PTS,(((T-1)*(1+7*T/4+1-7/4)/2+1)/T)*PTS)'" -an output.mp4
```

should do that, with the exception of the first second being at a normal frame rate.

Conceptually, I found it easiest to do this graphically. Please see the image, where x axis is time and y axis is PTS.

[image: Concept of method]

Where [image]

I am using the setpts filter.

The PTS (presentation timestamp) tells when to show the frame, so PTS*1 means to show it at the same time in the output as in the input, where PTS*0.5 tells to show it at 50% of input time etc.

So

```
setpts='if(between(T,0,1),PTS
```

means to keep the framerate same for the first second (this mostly due to the fact that one cannot divide with a zero). After which, the *Area* A1 is 1*1 = 1.

At t1=1s we start to decrease the framerate by telling each frame to come at a later time than in the input. The area A2 is a trapezoid where the area is calculated by the average of the sides times the base. Base is T - 1 and average of sides is ( 1 + ( 7 * T/4 + 1 - 7/4 ) ) / 2 (from creating a function for the line). To get the PTS of any given frame between 1 and 5 seconds, we must add the area of all (one in this case) previous areas and divide by the area of PTS*1, which equals T.

Thus from 1s to 5s, the PTS is calculated by

```
((T-1)*(1+7*T/4+1-7/4)/2+1)/T)*PTS
```

Unfortunately using the same method for audio in ffmpeg drops a lot of data and results in badly breaking sound (for speed-up at least). As I can accurately calculate the duration of the video (it is the same as the areas A1+A2), I ended up using audacity to try and fit each variable rate portion manually.

Comment: This does not work for me - still stuttering and about half the speed at playback.

Comment: Is your input video 60fps or more? If you want to slow it to half the speed, it needs to be at least that, otherwise obvious stuttering will occur. The command is only valid for 5 seconds, after that it will continue to slow the video indefinitely. At 5 seconds it will go half the speed.

Comment: Sorry, this goes to 1/8 speed at 5 seconds. and needs the 240 fps input to not stutter visibly

Comment: ok, thanks, I tried to use a 60fps video and convert it to 25 fps